# Why can't a class or an interface receive private or protected access modifiers?

Tags: java, access-modifiers

I am reading some Java text and the text says that we can only apply `public` or `default` access modifier for class and interface. Therefore, it is a compiling error if we declare:

```
private class A {}
```

or

```
protected class A{}
```

I am just curious why a class or an interface cannot receive `private` or `protected` access modifiers?

Comment: It is not a compiling error if we declare private class A { } or protected class B { } as long as A and B are not top-level classes.

Comment: I believe the default access for interfaces is public, so in effect an interface is always public.

Comment: @Adriaan Koster No. That rule applies *inside* interfaces, but not to interfaces themselves.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`private` means "only visible within the enclosing class".

`protected` means "only visible within the enclosing class and any subclasses, and also anywhere in the enclosing class's package".

`private`, therefore, has no meaning when applied to a top-level class; the same goes for the first part of the definition of `protected`. The second part of `protected` *could* apply, but it is covered by the default (package-protected) modifier, so `protected` is part meaningless and part redundant.

Both `private` and `protected` can be (and frequently are) applied to nested classes and interfaces, just never top-level classes and interfaces.

Answer (score 16):

top level classes can only have `public` or `default` access, but internal classes can have `private access`:

```
public class TestClassAccess
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new TestClassAccess().new TestClassPrivateAccess();
    }

    private class TestClassPrivateAccess
    {
        TestClassPrivateAccess()
        {
            System.out.println("I'm a private class");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: good examples.  internal classes can also be static.  internal interfaces and enums are implicitly static.

Answer (score 5):

There are only two use cases for class visibility at the top level (a) Visible everywhere (b) Visible only within the package. Hence only two modifiers (`public` and default). If class is `public`, then it is visible to all classes. If there is no access modifier, then it is visible only for classes within the same package.

Had there been more use cases for class visibility at top level, Java language would have provided more modifiers.

Comment: Firstly there ARE more cases for visibility than Java provides (see eg c#) and secondly you can have classes with protected or private modifiers - just no top level modifiers.

Comment: @Voo, there are only two use cases at top level. I believe question implied that as it said any other modifier gave compilation error

Comment: visibility of class means?

Comment: if class A can access (create, call member functions etc) class B, then class B is said to be visible to class A.