# The use of visibility modifiers in Java

Tags: java, modifier

```
class Orange{

    Orange(){
    }

}
```

What is the difference between the usage of the modifier - in this case, package-private - in front of the class and in front of the constructor? I think the modifier in front of the constructor means it is allowed to instantiate an instance of the class `Orange`. But what about the modifier in front of the class?

Comment: is that valid java?, you can read an article on modifiers in any good book

Comment: You can't have package as a class / method modifier.

Comment: -1 for asking invalid syntax...  However, I bet he means the default visibility for this.

Comment: Do you mean access modifiers? public, private and protected.]

Comment: yes. i can understand the mean of access modifier for method or a field. But what if it is in front of class?

Comment: Okay.  Who lied to all of you and said that this was invalid syntax?

Comment: This is valid syntax and I find it to be the best practice how visibility should be defined, see my reasoning below.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To start with there are 4 access levels created by 3 access modifiers.

1. public - accessible everywhere
2. protected - accessible in the same package and in the children
3. default - accessible only in the same package
4. private - accessible only in the same class.

You are correct about - Modifiers at the level of constructors are directly related to the instantiation of the class.

**Modifiers at the level of Class decide the accessibility of the Class.**

Comment: Modifiers at the level of Class decide the accessibility of the Class. what this mean? A class is access though the keyword import?

Comment: OP is talking about modifiers on the class itself, not methods.

Comment: ok here is the deal. A class can only be public or default i.e you can only use one modifier which is public at the class level. Suppose you don't specify and access modifier while writing the class(default access level) and try to access it in an another package, it wont be accessible. **The import will not be allowed**

Answer (score 5):

First, to assuage any fears, the code you've provided **is** perfectly valid Java syntax.

In effect, you've created a class that can only be instantiated/used by other classes in the default package.  It would also work if you defined it in a package (e.g. `package foo;`) since only the classes in package `foo` could see this class).

Now, to the crux of the question.

[There are different ways to control access to fields and members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html). and they each do different things.

- `private` visibility is the least visible.  Only the defining class can access the field.
- No modifier, or `package private` is the second least visible.  The defining class *and* all classes within the package may access the field, but subclasses and the rest of the world cannot.
- `protected` is the second most visible. Only other classes are prohibited from accessing the field.
- `public` is the most visible.  *Everything* can access the field.

Modifiers at the level of the class get interesting.  This comes from the [Java Language Specification, §8.1.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1):

> The access modifier `public` (§6.6) pertains only to top level classes
>   (§7.6) and to member classes (§8.5), not to local classes (§14.3) or
>   anonymous classes (§15.9.5).
>
> The access modifiers `protected` and `private` (§6.6) pertain only to
>   member classes within a directly enclosing class or enum declaration
>   (§8.5).
>
> The modifier static pertains only to member classes (§8.5.1), not to
>   top level or local or anonymous classes.
>
> **It is a compile-time error if the same modifier appears more than once
>   in a class declaration.**
>
> If two or more (distinct) class modifiers appear in a class
>   declaration, then it is customary, though not required, that they
>   appear in the order consistent with that shown above in the production
>   for `ClassModifier`.

In general, a class declaration appears something like this:

```
ClassDeclaration:
    NormalClassDeclaration
    EnumDeclaration

NormalClassDeclaration:
    ClassModifiers(opt) class Identifier TypeParameters(opt)
                        Super(opt) Interfaces(opt) ClassBody
```

Anything with (opt) is considered optional.

So, what does this pare down to?

- The JLS mandates that a class does not need a [class] modifier.
- The JLS mandates that, if a [class] modifier is present, then it follows one of these rules:

  - If the modifier is `public`, then it is only applicable to top level classes and member classes.
  - If the modifier is `protected` or `private`, then it is only applicable to member classes within a directly enclosing class or enumeration.
  - The `static` modifier may appear, but is only applicable to member classes.

[Constructors have a similar rule set.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8)

```
ConstructorDeclaration:
    ConstructorModifiers(opt) ConstructorDeclarator
                                Throws(opt) ConstructorBody

ConstructorDeclarator:
    TypeParameters(opt) SimpleTypeName ( FormalParameterList(opt) )
```

Again, this breaks down to:

- The JLS mandates that a constructor does not need a [constructor] modifier.
- The JLS mandates that a constructor modifier cannot contain [`abstract`, `static`, `final`, `native`, `strictfp`, or `synchronized`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.3).
- The JLS mandates, if no access modifier is specified for the constructor of a normal class, the constructor has **default** access (§8.8.3, emphasis mine).

Answer (score 3):

You can only declare a public or default class (in case of top level classes only) in Java and these modifiers decide the accessiblity of the class.

I also suggest you to see "[Why can't a class or an interface receive private or protected access modifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734849/why-cant-a-class-or-an-interface-receive-private-or-protected-access-modifiers)"

Now as for as constructor concerns, a constructor will have aaccess-control of type default when no access-modifier is defined explicitly. So this constructor will have a Package Level Access. Only those class which are defined within that package as that of the class with this default constructor will be able to access it. See "[Aren't Java constructors public by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668922/arent-java-constructors-public-by-default)"

If the constructor is made private, then only the code within that class can access this. 
For a better understanding of modifiers, you need to see "[Access Modifiers In Java](http://javapapers.com/core-java/access-modifiers-in-java-explain/)"

Comment: *`private`, therefore, has no meaning when applied to a top-level class*. By the way, you can apply this to a **non** top-level class e.g. static inner classes.

Comment: Dear In OP's example , he didn't show any inner class.So I am just answering in his prospective.Anyway I have edited my question

Answer (score 1):

Modifier of class defines who can access the class. For example `public` class can be accessed by classes from any package, if no modifier is written the class can be accessed by classes from *the same* package only.

Modifier of constructor, method and field has the same meaning. However `private` and `protected` have more sense. Private can be accessed from the current class only. Protected from its subclasses as far as from just classes from the same package.

Concerning to your question about constructor. Class can have several constructors. Some of them can be private, some other public. You are right that there is no sense to make constructor public if class is package protected: no-one outside package can call this class anyway.

This is exactly like writing public constructors for abstract classes. Since abstract class cannot be instantiated itself its constructors should be `protected` or `private` although compiler does not care about this.

BTW using default package is not commonly used and not recommended technique.

Comment: Depends on the scenario.  If you have a method you wish to expose for the sake of unit testing, but not anything else, then you could declare it as package private, and ensure that the test uses the same package.

Answer (score 1):

The ***use*** and ***types*** of `class` level modifiers:

http://javapapers.com/core-java/access-modifiers-in-java-explain/

The ***use*** and ***types*** of `constructor` level modifiers:

http://www.careercup.com/question?id=296844#commentThread302715

Answer (score 0):

Class modifiers work similarly to method modifiers. Public, private, final, abstract, etc. work.

Public allows the class and its methods to be accessed by classes from any package.

No modifier only allows classes to be access from it's defined package.

Private would prevent all access (no point to this if using with a top-level class).

Abstract classes allow you to create *child* classes derived from the *parent* (abstract) class. For example, you can make an Abstract Shape class and have a Rectangle class extend shape, inheriting all its methods, variables, and forcing it to define any abstract methods.

Answer (score 0):

**Access Modifiers:**

- Public - {Can access anywhere in the project}
- Private - {Can access    only inside the class}
- Protected - {Can access within the package    and sub classes}
- Default - {can access within the package}

**Non-Access Modifiers:**

- Static - {for creating class variable and method}
- Final - {for creating finalized variable and method}
- Abstract - {for creating abstract method and class}
- Synchronized - {for threads}

Some brief discussion on the above modifiers in this [link](http://vhariprasath.blogspot.in/2014/04/modifiers-in-java.html). Refer it for the better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I find the best visibility level in Java to be the `default` visibility i.e. *package* visibility, because it enables unit test classes to access all the methods, if the test is placed in the same package as the main class.

Also *package* visibility is shorter to write since you can omit the visibility declaration, so there is less boiler plate.

The second best visibility level is `protected`, since in some cases you can create your test classes as sub-classes of your main class. However, as stated before, package visibility works better in most cases, if you use packages properly.

Third, typically if you run Sonar and do code review and static analysis on large projects, I have found out that typically 80% of the methods are `public`, and 20% are `private`/`protected`. Thus, the main idea of using private or protected methods is to protect the data/properties from being accessed by bypassing the accessors. Most of the methods will be typically public anyways.

The most useless visibility level (but unfortunately commonly used) is `private` as it's impossible to test (without using Reflection and modifying the visibility to something else). Also, `private` prohibits code re-use in sub-classes, which is the main idea of using object oriented paradigm in the first place, and thus should be avoided. For the same reasons keyword `final` should be avoided in most cases.

Thus, I find your example to be the best practice how to define the visibility levels, except that your constructor is not public :). However, you are missing the package declaration and unit tests.