# Inner class vs public inner class in Java

Tags: java

I realized inner classes can be declared as public. What are practical use cases of public inner classes and how are they different than inner classes declared without public keyword?

```
public class OuterClass{
    class InnerClass{

    }
}

public class OuterClass{
    public class InnerClass{

    }
}
```

Comment: The difference is that if it's public you can use it from another package. Same as public means on any class.

Comment: See [What is the difference between "public class" and just "class"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16779245/3890632)

Comment: As for a use case, I suppose it could be used as a organization tool (though having it as separate files under a package would be better). For example, if you want to have a bunch of Shape objects then you could make them nested under a Shape class to call `Shape.Square`, `Shape.Circle`, ect. Typically a nested class would be private and tightly connected to the parent class such as a Node class inside a List class.

Comment: I confess that, even after 20+ years of Java programming, this still surprised me. I never knew that an inner class could be public. I guess I didn't know because I never came across a real use for such a thing, and I still can't think of a real-world application, with all due respect to @TimHunter.

Comment: @KevinBoone No, I agree. There are far better tools for organization purposes, that's just the only ill-advised but still potentially usable scenario I can think of for a public inner.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is when passing an instance through a method/constructor.

Here is some code to show what I mean.
**Class com.test.OutterClass.**

```
package com.test;

public class OutterClass {

    // public class
    public class InnerClass {

    }
    
    // not public class
    class InnerClass1 {

    }
}
```

**Class com.test2.TestClass**

```
package com.test2;

public class TestClass {


     // Works, because OutterClass.InnerClass is public.
     TestClass(OutterClass.InnerClass t) {
     
    }

    // Doesn't work because OutterClass.InnerClass1 is not public.
    TestClass(OutterClass.InnerClass1 t) {
    
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the difference btw class InnerClass1 and private class InnerClass1?