# How did the private method called by a reference object variable

Tags: java

How did bird able to call the method fly if it's private

```
public class Bird {
    private static void fly() { 
        System.out.println("Bird is flying"); 
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        fly(); // make sense
        Bird bird = new Bird();
        bird.fly();
    }
}
```

Comment: Because it's in the same class.

Comment: Because your accessing it in the same class.

Comment: learn about static keyword

Comment: change 
`private void fly() { 
        System.out.println("Bird is flying"); 
    } `

to 

`private static void fly() { 
        System.out.println("Bird is flying"); 
    }`

Comment: Read this [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) and this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16727414/the-use-of-visibility-modifiers-in-java). That will make it clear.

Comment: okay, I understand  now. thanks for the answers

Answer (score 1):

The access modifier *private* means that the method can only be seen from within the class. 
Since you are within the class, this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

In Java there are 3 modifiers:

-Public: You can access from anywhere

-Private: You can access from the same class

-Protected You can access from the same package and from any class that extends the class in which it is.

Your method is private and you are accessing it in the same class.